# Login functionality is not working when the IP Address of the server was bind to the Website in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

What could be causing the login function in an ASP.NET Core MVC Web App, as depicted in the provided code, to experience issues when binding the application to a specific IP address in IIS? Additionally, how can you ensure the proper functioning of the login feature when configuring the app with specific IP bindings on the server, taking into consideration the appsettings.json configuration?

Here is the **Program.cs** code:

```
using Amenities_Scheduler.Common.Classes;
using Amenities_Scheduler.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PROD")));

builder.Services.AddIdentity<LoginModel, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["system_gen_access_token"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
    options.SaveToken = true;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Hashing:ValidIssuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Hashing:ValidAudience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Hashing:SecretKey"]))
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();

    options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        policy.RequireRole("Admin"); // Allow only users with the "Admin" role
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new[] { JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme };
    });
});

builder.Services.AddSession(); 

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseStatusCodePages(context => {
    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    if (response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized ||
            response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        response.Cookies.Delete("uid");
    response.Redirect("Dashboard");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Dashboard}/{action=Dashboard}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Here is the Action in the Dashboard for the Login

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Dashboard(DashboardViewModel dashboardModel)
        {
            UserInput input = new UserInput() 
            {
                Email = dashboardModel.Login.Email,
                Password = dashboardModel.Login.PasswordHash
            };
            _ilogic = new GetUserLogic();
            SystemResult loginResult = _ilogic.DoSystemProcess(config, input);

            if (loginResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                var loginModel = loginResult.executionResult[typeof(DashboardViewModel).FullName] as DashboardViewModel;
                dashboardModel = loginModel;
                dynamic user = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dashboardModel.Login);
                var hashedCookie = _hasher.Encrypt(user);
                var token = GenerateToken(dashboardModel.Login);
                Response.Cookies.Append("system_gen_access_token", token, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    Secure = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                });
                Response.Cookies.Append("uid", hashedCookie, new CookieOptions
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                    Secure = true,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
                });
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = loginResult.ErrorMessage;
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
        }
```

And here is the **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DEV": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Amenity_Scheduler;Integrated Security=True",
    "PROD": "Server=Sample_server;Database=Amenity_Scheduler;User=test;Password=test;Integrated Security=False"
  },
  "Hashing": {
    "SecretKey": "SpJsDO1jKOqjwVxjdFLiY4qunetdnErO",
    "ValidIssuer": "https://localhost:7198",
    "ValidAudience": "https://localhost:7198"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I already tried passing the IP Address of the server to the ValidIssuer and ValidAudience in the appsettings.json and yet the behavior is still the same.

I thought this might work due to the initial value of this config settings is from the launchsettings.json.

Comment: IIS does not support the latest encryption algorithms that are using in TLS 1.3 certificates.  Is connection completing or are you getting a timeout (connection did not complete).  Authentication occurs after the connection completes.  I cannot tell if the authentication is failing or the authentication is never taking place because the connection did not complete.  Did you get a response with a status code? When you do not get a response it indicates the connection did not complete.  Also you may be using a proxy and the proxy connection is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot that I don't have an SSL on the current server.

So I just need to set the `Secure = False` because if its `true` it wont create a JWT Token.

```
Response.Cookies.Append("system_gen_access_token", token, new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    Secure = False,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
});
Response.Cookies.Append("uid", hashedCookie, new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
    Secure = False,
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
});
```

Comment: ADDITION: Don't worry. I will set this again to True once I get the SSL for this application.